# Which has better SEO for a large amount of similar products? Shorter or longer product descriptions

Tags: seo, google, ecommerce

I am building a e-commerce site with a large amount (100s) of similar products. Product descriptions will be batch generated and will therefore be very similar, with only slight modifications in the text.

Considering that it is better for SEO to have longer product descriptions, but duplication penalties might happen, and Google might consider the site to be 'spammy'. What will be worse for SEO? Shorter descriptions or a possible duplication penalty?

Comment: By "similar products" do you mean something like different colors of the same product? Can you provide an example?

Comment: By similar products I mean maps of cities towns. They are separate products, however they will have the same description apart from the city names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine with the longer descriptions because a map of Chicago, IL is completely different than, say, a map of Los Angeles, CA.

Even though your product descriptions are basically the same, it's ok because they're going to rank for different keywords.

Now let's say you want to add new *style* of map to your collection, you would need to write a new boilerplate description for all of those products. Otherwise, it would be duplicate content.